# The User UID is not the same with document id in Firestore Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have created a function to add a new user to Firestore Database:

```
public void addNewUser(String email, String username, String profile_photo){
        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(); // this is instantiated here, just to show you 
        User user = new User(userID, (long) 1, email, StringManipulation.condenseUsername(username), username, profile_photo);

        db.collection("Users").add(user)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot added with ID: " + documentReference.getId());
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Error adding document", e);
                    }
                });
    }
```

And a function to fetch the data from the database, waiting for all the fields to appear in-app.

```
public UserSettings RetrieveUserSettings(){
        Log.d(TAG, "getUserAccountSettings: retrieving user account settings from firebase");

        User settings = new User();
        DocumentReference userRef;
        FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        

                try {
                    userRef = db.collection("Users")
                                .document(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());

                    userRef.get()
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                                    if(documentSnapshot.exists())
                                    {
                                        settings.setDisplay_name(documentSnapshot.getString("display_name"));
                                        settings.setUsername(documentSnapshot.getString("username"));
                                        settings.setProfile_photo(documentSnapshot.getString("profile_photo"));
                                        settings.setEmail(documentSnapshot.getString("email"));
                                        settings.setPhone_number(documentSnapshot.getLong("phone_number"));
                                        settings.setUser_id(documentSnapshot.getString("user_id"));
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        Log.d(TAG, "doc not fount in getUserSettinghs ");
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: failed to fetch data");
                                }
                            });

                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "getUserAccountSettings: NULLPointerException: " + e.getMessage());
                }
                Log.e(TAG, "getUserAccountSettings: retrieved user_account_settings information: " + settings.toString());

        return new UserSettings(settings);
    }
```

When I authenticate, this is the User UID that is generated: E5bBL0D9lCSKy5a0YdUJjuMVuUT2, but when I call the addNewUser function, my Firestore Database looks like this :
[image: database], so it is obvious that the User UID generated at authentication is not the same with the document id, which is :
XWwnRBklieJXSxokQuNe.Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: You're never specifying the document path here. Calling `CollectionRererence.add()` will generate a new document ID for you. So instead you should 'navigate' to the specific document path you want.

Comment: And can you suggest to me how to do this? Because I wrote add(user), the user includes all the fields, even user-id

Comment: Sure, you can call `CollectionReference.document(id).set(user)`. The `add` method is just a shortcut for the same, but with a random document ID. Remember there's a big difference between the document ID and the fields. Imagine a text file that has `CODEnoob` as the first line, the filename isn't necessarily `CODEnoob` too.

Comment: But how this will retrieve all my data from firestore ? For me, this seems to be as addNewUser function that I've been use

Comment: You never said you have an issue with retrieving data? I thought your problem was the ID generated with the `addNewUser`method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @HenryTwist mentioned in his comment, when using the following line of code:

```
db.collection("Users").add(user).addOnSuccessListener(/* ... /*);
```

You are adding a new "User" object to the "Users" collection using a random ID. The above line of code does the same thing as:

```
db.collection("Users").document().set(user).addOnSuccessListener(/* ... /*);
```

When you call CollectionReference's [add()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/CollectionReference.html#add(java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%3E)) method or CollectionReference's [document()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/CollectionReference.html#document()) method without passing any parameters, the built-in generator used by Firestore will always generate a **random** ID each time one of the methods is called.

As I see from the following line of code:

```
userRef = db.collection("Users").document(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
```

You have already implemented [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth), which is good. That being said, when you want to add new "User" object to the database, use the UID that comes from authentication process, as shown below:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
db.collection("Users").document(uid).set(user).addOnSuccessListener(/* ... /*);
```

In this way, the ID of the document will **match** the value of the "user_id" property in the database.